# Redirect using Special Character %3C

Tags: c#, regex, redirect, iis

How would one write the match url for redirect rule that includes %3C which is the < character

sample url : www.test.com/product/product-detail/123-magazine-%3C43K

match url= ^product/product-detail/123-magazine-%3C43K--- does not redirect

Comment: Nice. Thank you for the very detailed example. This is very helpful. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: If your issue is solved then I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could try below rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="special chr rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{UNENCODED_URL}" pattern="^/product/product\-detail/([a-zA-Z0-9%-+].+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.sample1.com/product/product-detail/{C:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use the {UNENCODED _URL} and suggested pattern.  I assumed that a bit of regex was needed but did not know that it entailed your suggested [a-zA-Z0-9%-+].  Again thanks for that. My link now redirects as it should